# Isolating large amounts of information into factories from controllers (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I'm a little new to Angular, so I'm not really sure what the standards are when it comes to writing an app that has something like this.

I had some functions and content I needed to share across controllers, so I isolated them out into a factory so the controllers could act independently of each other.

But then I realized most, if not all of the logic and content for those few controllers were part of what needed to be shared. Now the controllers I initially created to handle the logic (prior to realizing I would need to isolate their information) are empty.

Some of the functions I moved over simply involve saving passed-in values into different variables that *could* be controller specific and wouldn't impact dependency injection, but since they deal with a lot of information in the factory, I thought it would be easier to simply keep them there rather than move some small functions and variables back to the controller. So now I have two empty controllers that I might as well delete.

My question: In a situation like this where you need to share information that would otherwise be isolated into its own controllers, is it better to simply have a factory that talks minimally to some controllers just to share data, but holds all of the logic and data itself inside the factory? Or would it be better to designate controllers to hold small pieces of the specific logic, despite it taking most of its data from the factory anyways.

Is it better to use controllers to back up my factory, even if the question at hand doesn't call for them?

Comment: I prefer that pattern of very thin controllers just providing view interaction with factories

Comment: Like justin, I mostly only use my controllers to bind to events or listen to scope changes. Everything else happens in my "service" layer  (module.service, module.factory works too).